# Bash relative path to absolute path

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sh

I am trying to convert a relative path to an absolute path in my shell script.
This: `/home/admin/Downloads/old/t2` should be something like this: `../../old/t2`.
I want to do this because the rsync command needs an absolute path.

Comment: `readlink -f` or `readlink -m` will do this, on a GNU platform.

Comment: replace home/admin with $HOME